# Azure Batch - Automatically delete completed tasks

Tags: azure, azure-batch

Is there a way to automatically delete task in job after successful execution?

I'm setting retention time to 24 hours and it correctly deletes the data associated with a task, but not the task itself. I know this is the expected behavior.

But how do i delete successful tasks and only keep tasks that failed? Is there a way to do that automatically, like setting the retention time constraint on a task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such functionality currently does not exist, please see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/Batch/issues/35) for tracking.

While not ideal, you can utilize a [recurring job schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/jobschedule) with the appropriate credentials to clean up successful tasks, other services such as [Azure Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/scheduler/), [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/functions/), or custom cron scripts to accomplish what you need.